# Expandable Queue in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

For my homework, I have been asked to implement an expandable queue in c++. We are given a header file which we cannot change. The header file has a dynamic array, _front, _size (current number of elements in the queue) and _capacity.

If we try and push an element on the queue that would be "out of bounds" or greater than the capacity, we are asked to created a new queue with double the old capacity. How am I suppose to implement dequeue and enqueue without a point to next or an _rear variable?

Any sort of hint would help, not looking for an entire solution.

Comment: Well if you have an array and a size/capacity, what's to stop you from doing `arr + sz - 1` to get a pointer to the last item or `arr + 1` for the next item?

Comment: @scohe001 can you explain this more?

Comment: You do have a `_rear` variable - it's  `_size`.

Comment: When you need to expand, allocate a buffer twice as large as your capacity, copy the items from the old array over, swap the pointers, and delete the one for the old smaller buffer.

Comment: As tempting as it may look, stay away from using `realloc`. If you are operating on objects it can bite you in some weird and interesting ways.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know the data type of the queue, let's assume it is an integer. You can then use the information given (assuming you cannot edit the header file as you stated and are only given access to a few items):

Header file

```
class Queue
{
public:
  Queue()
  {
    _front = new int[10];
    _size = 0;
    _capacity = 10;
  }
  ~Queue()
  {
    delete[] _front;
  }

  int* _front;
  int _size;
  int _capacity;
};
```

In your code you can then do something like (NOTE: this isn't tested):

```
#include "Queue.h"

void add(Queue*q, int i)
{
  // If there is room then add it.
  if(q->_size < q->_capacity)
  {
    q->_size++;
    *(q->_front + q->_size - 1) = i;
  }
  else
  {
    // If full then create a new array.
    int* arr = new int[q->_capacity * 2];

    // Copy over the old data.
    for(int j = 0; j < q->_capacity; j++)
    {
      *(arr + j) = *(q->_front + j);
    }

    q->_capacity *= 2;   // Update parameter.
    delete[] q->_front;  // Delete memory.
    q->front = arr;      // Point to new array.
    arr = nullptr;       // c++11

    q->_size++;          // Same as above when there was room.
    *(q->_front + q->_size - 1) = i;
  }
}

int main()
{
   Queue q;

   add(&q, 1234);   
}
```

This would be much nicer if you could add functions to the header file. Since I do not know the limits of what you're allowed to do I created an external function.